# Parsing date in different culture

Tags: c#, locale

I'm developing a software that should be used from a US customer.
On my pc (italian) I use

```
CultureInfo cultureUS = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s, cultureUS);
```

and this works with a string like **Sat, Sep 8, 2012**.
But when my software is used on customer pc, he gets the error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Why? What's wrong?
What should I use to let it work everywhere?

**EDIT:**
just to avoid confusion: I read those kind of dates both from web and files and I need to parse them and then use them (in that format) to write some other file.
So I thought I did not need to convert them to a "standard" format and then convert them back again: I'd like to use them from that format and write them directly to files...
And this is the reason I decided to use the code I wrote....

Comment: What has your customer entered? What locale is your user using? Did the user _change_ any of the regional settings of the OS?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to parse a string that was generated using a different culture then `en-US` the solution is to generate the string using the same specific culture you will use to parse the generated string.  There are dozens of questions on this subject.

Comment: @Oded: I'd like this string to be parsed on every pc; this is the reason I specify a culture... Should I use a different way? By the way, that string should be parsed... it's correct IMHO...

Comment: if you intend to *visualize* stored DateTime on all cultures, you may need to run not some specific (en-US), but CurrentCulture. Store DateTime in some predefined, unique format.

Comment: The way your code is written, and assuming the user didn't mess around with their culture settings, it should indeed work on every PC for your example input. Of course, we assume that the user will have the `en-US` culture installed on their computer.

Comment: @Oded: he lives in Tennesse... so I "think" he has that culture installed... but naturally I cannot be sure...

Comment: Heh... Tennesse? I believe they have their own distinct culture ;) Kidding aside, this should simply work. Find out what the client is passing in as a date.

Comment: @Oded: "Of course, we assume that the user will have the en-US culture installed"... what do you mean? In my pc I have only italian language installed, but this works. Isn't Framework responsible to parse that string in defined culture?

Comment: Language <> Locale. If you go to the regional settings of your OS, you will see in different tabs several lists of locations/formats for different areas/locations. These are not identical on all computers and depend on the installation locale. They can also be uninstalled for example.

Comment: @Oded: OMG, I did not think about it... you're completely right; but a question: I'm able to transform a date using that format `dateFrom.ToString("ddd, MMM dd, yyyy", cultureUS);` so shouldn't this locale be installed? Take a look at my edit if you have time. Thanks Oded!!

Comment: @Tigran: read my edited question if you have some time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marco - I was just trying to cover all options. I would find it difficult to believe the issue is with the US culture not being present. But without knowing _exactly_ what the string that is failing to parse, I can't help any more.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "D", cultureInfo);
```

edit

For exact time date format, you can try:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "ddd, MMM dd, yyyy", cultureInfo);
```

Comment: That will fail to parse `Sat, Sep 8, 2012`. At least provide the correct format string.

Comment: done. Would you like a donut and hot tea to go with the correct format string? :)

Comment: No need for that tone. If you are going to give code, give code that will work for the OP. Regardless, "D" doesn't work with that format (getting a FormatException).

Comment: I do not necessarily agree. I pointed him to ParseExact, and he can dig and find the format he wants. Besides, you are more than welcome to edit my answer, instead of being high handed with me.

Comment: No @tranceporter, string you see is the one I have. Anyway thanks for your contrib. Just a suggestion: Oded is a guru here, listen to him, because he's always polite, believe me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to localizations but perhaps this might work for you:

```
DateTime.Parse(date, new DateTimeFormatInfo()
                         { LongDatePattern = "ddd, MMM dd, YYYY" });
```

It appears to be working for me for the strings I've thrown at it in your string format, but I haven't tested it with varying cultures.