# Convert string to datetime on server 2008

Tags: c#, datetime

i have problem when i try to convert in c# this string:

```
Úterý, 07 Červen 2016 13:06
```

to datetime, because i import this to sql. 
I try this:

```
DateTime.Parse("Úterý, 07 Červen 2016 13:06")
DateTime.Parse("Úterý, 07 Červen 2016 13:06").Date
Convert.ToDateTime("Úterý, 07 Červen 2016 13:06")
```

On my windows 10 i havent any problem, but when i try in sql server 2008 i have this error:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown
>   word starting at index 0

Have you any ideas please?

Comment: maybe the culture? try changing the culture of the sql there

Comment: Where are you trying to change the date to a date, in c# or in a sql command in sql server...

Comment: Please, have a look at `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: @Miquel Coll : Can you be more specific please...thanks

Comment: @BugFinder : in c#..

Comment: put `set language french` at the beginning -- replace french for whatever language it is

Comment: Can you post the SQL query string you used where you get the error from sql?

Comment: what I said in my previous comment is in SQL; for C# you should use: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");` // change es-ES for the corresponding culture

Comment: Google translate claims this is Czech. Tried `SET LANGUAGE CZECH` and then `SELECT CAST('Úterý, 07 Červen 2016 13:06' As datetime)`, resulted with `Převod řetězce znaků na datový typ Datum a čas se nezdařil.`, that translates back to English as `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` btw, the date is Tuesday, June 7th.

Comment: I have it!!! :)   DateTime.Parse("Úterý, 07 Červen 2016 13:06", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("cs-CZ")));   Thanks for help all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DateTime.ParseExact` method, like this (providing that the initial string is in *Czech* culture):

```
  String source = "Úterý, 07 Červen 2016 13:06";

  DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm", 
    new CultureInfo("cs-CZ"));
```

format explanation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

```
dddd  The full name of the day of the week.
dd    The day of the month, from 01 through 31.
MMMM  The full name of the month.
yyyy  The year as a five-digit number.
H     The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.
mm    The minute, from 00 through 59.
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `mm` instead of `m` because it looks like single digit minutes have a leading zero.

Comment: @Soner Gönül: thank you! I've edited the answer: `06` minutes really looks like leading `0` is mandatory

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have string format of DateTime in Czech:

```
String str = "Úterý, 07 Červen 2016 13:06"
```

Try changing culture to preferred one:

```
CultureInfo fr = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("cs-CZ");
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "D", fr);

// or use this format:
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "ddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm", fr);
```

Reference: [Parsing date in different culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937256/parsing-date-in-different-culture)

CMIIW.

Comment: The last suggestion ("or use this format") is incorrect one, since `"ddd"` stands for "The abbreviated name of the day of the week." while `Úterý` is full name of the day of the week; and `"hh"` is for using a 12-hour clock from *01 to 12* (so it'll fail on `13`)